# Reading multiple files in a directory starting from a specific row

Tags: r

I am trying to read multiple files in R from the working directory and would like to read like to read from the 7th row for each file. I am not sure how can i do that

I found how to read an individual file with this:

```
data = read.csv(file.choose (),  skip = 6 )
```

or I can read multiple files like this:

```
j = list.files()         
     d = lapply(j, read.csv)
```

could you please help me with how can i read multiple files starting from the 7th row?

Comment: From the help page, `... optional arguments to FUN`. In your example, `read.csv` == FUN, so you can just pass the additional arguments after declaring FUN, i.e. `lapply, j, read.csv, skip = 6)`. See `?lapply` for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @James's answer, using `lapply` only reads the files into a list, not into a common `data.frame`. From your question it is not obvious if you want this. But I'll add it for completeness sake anyway.

To be able to identify to which file a row in the common `data.frame` belonged originally, I often add a column with the filename. In pseudo-code this would look something like:

```
files = list.files()
data_list = lapply(files, function(f) {
     dat = read.csv(fname, skip = 6)
     dat$fname = fname
     return(dat)
   })
data_df = do.call("rbind", data_list)
```

Alternatively, you could use the awesome `plyr` library, which does the exact same thing in:

```
library(plyr)
files = list.files()
data_df = ldply(files, read.csv, skip = 6)
```

I have not tested this pseudo-code, so it could be that there are some flaws yet. But you get the basic idea. One problem for example could be that `ldply` does not automatically adds the filename as a column. Then you need to use the function call as I did using `lapply`. In that case, `ldply` saves you the `do.call` step. Note that `plyr` supports a progress bar (nice for long processes) and parallel processing.

note:

- I like more descriptive names than `j` and `d`. This makes the code easier to read.

Comment: thats thats explain a lot with the issue I am having now! :)

Answer (score 6):

Just combine the two. You can pass in named arguments to a function in `lapply`:

```
d <- lapply(j, read.csv, skip=6)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought, i must have spelled something wrong, I tried this before and didn't work, now working just fine :)