# R loop for creating data frame

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of samples in the object my.ID:

```
head(my.ID)
```

returns:

```
[1] PATL1 PATL2 PATL9 PCAN1 PCAN2 PCAN3
117 Levels: PATL1 PATL2 PATL9...
```

For each sample, I have a file, called like that:

`Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PATL1.windowed.pi`

With the name of the sample in the middle (here PATL1)

I want to create a data frame for each sample where first column is the name of the  sample (PATL1 for instance, which is listed in my.ID), and the second column is the column called PI from its associated data frame (in my example: Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PATL1.windowed.pi$PI.

I tried multiple loops, changes a few stuff but never worked.
I think that it's because I don't manage to properly define the value in the data.frame command.

Can someone show me how to change the loop so that it works?

```
for (i in 1:(length(my.ID))){
  my.value <- noquote(paste0("Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_",my.ID[i],".windowed.pi$PI"))
  cur.file <- data.frame(group=my.ID[i], value=as.name(my.value))
  my.name <- my.ID[i]
  assign(paste(my.name), cur.file)
}
```

Comment: `my.files <- paste0("Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_",my.ID,".windowed.pi")` and then `result <- lapply(my.files, FUN=...)` The function in `FUN=` is for working on one file (with the given filename).

Comment: Thanks Jogo, for your reply. Unfortunately, I'm still,lost! Now OK, I have the list of files, but I still don't manage to create the dataframe. I truie this and not working
for (i in 1:(length(my.ID))){
  my.files <- paste0("Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_",my.ID,".windowed.pi")
  my.pi <- paste0(my.files,"$PI")
  cur.file <- data.frame(group=my.ID[i], value=as.name(my.pi))
  my.name <- my.ID[i]
  assign(paste(my.name), cur.file)
}

Comment: Here is something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890209/reading-multiple-files-in-a-directory-starting-from-a-specific-row

Comment: Thanks Jogo. I have no issue reading all my files. They are already read with a previous loop. My issue is on creating a dafarame where the ID name is in the first column and the second is the column PI from the object Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PATL1.windowed.pi$PI (in the case of the sample PATL1)

Comment: How did you read all the dataframes? It is not a good idea to generate a bunch of similar object. Use a list for that objects!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to generate a bunch of similar object. Use a list for that objects!

For you (with the informations from your answer) it could be:

```
my.files <- list.files(path="Pi1_vcftools_indv/results/", pattern = "Pi_")

my.samples <- read.table("../../Samples/JudDP_sample_info_VCFsorted.2020.05.12.txt", header=TRUE)
my.ID <- my.samples$ID

mydata3 <- function(IDi, filei) {
  cur.file <- read.table(file = paste0("Pi1_vcftools_indv/results/",filei), sep = "\t", h=T)
  data.frame(group=IDi, value=cur.file)
}
L <- mapply(mydata3, my.ID, my.files)
names(L) <- my.ID
```

Here is a variant using `setwd()`:

```
my.samples <- read.table("../../Samples/JudDP_sample_info_VCFsorted.2020.05.12.txt", header=TRUE)
my.ID <- my.samples$ID

setwd("Pi1_vcftools_indv/results/")
my.files <- list.files(pattern = "Pi_")

mydata3 <- function(IDi, filei) {
  cur.file <- read.table(file=filei, sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
  data.frame(group=IDi, value=cur.file)
}
L <- mapply(mydata3, my.ID, my.files)
names(L) <- my.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand your question but is it as simple as this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

cur.file <- tibble(
  group = as.factor(c("PATL1", "PATL2", "PATL9", "PCAN1", "PCAN2", "PCAN3"))
)
```

**dplyr**

```
cur.file <- cur.file %>%
  mutate(value = paste0("Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_", group,".windowed.pi$PI"))
```

**baseR**

```
cur.file$value <- paste0("Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_", cur.file$group, ".windowed.pi$PI")
```

With this result:

```
> cur.file
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  group value                                              
  <fct> <chr>                                              
1 PATL1 Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PATL1.windowed.pi$PI
2 PATL2 Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PATL2.windowed.pi$PI
3 PATL9 Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PATL9.windowed.pi$PI
4 PCAN1 Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PCAN1.windowed.pi$PI
5 PCAN2 Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PCAN2.windowed.pi$PI
6 PCAN3 Pi_Win5kb_JudDP_2020.04.29.vcf_PCAN3.windowed.pi$PI
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it:

```
my.files <- list.files(path="Pi1_vcftools_indv/results/", pattern = "Pi_")
for (i in 1:(length(my.files))){
  my.samples <- read.table("../../Samples/JudDP_sample_info_VCFsorted.2020.05.12.txt",h=T); my.ID <- my.samples$ID
  cur.file <- read.table(file = paste0("Pi1_vcftools_indv/results/",my.files[i]), sep = "\t", h=T)
  my.df <- data.frame(group=my.ID[i], value=cur.file)
  my.name <- my.ID[i]
  assign(paste(my.name), my.df)
}
```

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect on the informations given in your answer.